# Передача аргумента в функцию через пробел

Tags: javascript

Просто интересно, реализуемл ли такое вообще?
Под передачей через пробел я подразумеваю что-то типа:

```
typeof "string"
```

Я знаю про обратные кавычки в ES6, но возможно ли это без них?

Comment: непонятно причем тут аргументы функции и `typeof` и обратные кавычки. можете более подробно описать что хотите? На каком-нибудь примере

Comment: Хотя я примерно начинаю понимать..... это как например в Java  параметром ожидать `Map`, а сунуть можно `HashMap` и `TreeMap`. Вы об этом?

Comment: Увы, я не знаком  java, но суть вот в чём: typeof ведь как принимает значение? Нужнго написать typeof и через пробел значение typeof smth. То-есть так же, как var или что-то в этом роде..

Comment: как я понимаю, автор вопроса хочет чтото типа такого : `myFunc "myData"`, и мне кажеться что это не реализуемо

Comment: Да, вы правильно поняли.. Жаль(

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/TypeScript   - это чтоли?))

Comment: вообще для js есть какие-то плагины - статические анализаторы. где-то валяются наверняка... типа такого https://stackoverflow.com/a/27015129/6104996